# How to retrieve objects simultaneously from database?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, algorithm

I'm building a social analytics website with `Django`.

Here is one of my `use cases`:

```
"Users" of the site analyze social media "profiles" (from Snapchat, Instagram, Twitter, etc...). 
Each social media "profile" is only analyzed once (and not more).
```

I have an `SQL` query that retrieves `profiles` in a queue. For instance, the first `5` `profiles` that are returned (when I repeat this query `5` times) are:

```
xmax123, darcy67, shop_hallmary10, christmas_shop987, lilybend_09
```

After the `user` analyzes the `profile` `xmax123`, `xmax123` will no longer appear for other `users` to analyze.

My problem is when multiple `users` call this SQL query concurrently, the same social media `profile` (`xmax123`) is returned for all `users`. In other words, when two `users` (`user 1` and `user 2`) call this SQL query at the same time, the same social media `profile` (`xmax123`) is returned for both of them. This means that `xmas123` will be analyzed twice by `2` different `users`, which is a problem.

I want to ensure that `user 1` gets `xmax123` and `user 2` gets `darcy67`, even when both `users` call this SQL query concurrently. What are some strategies to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe you query the user, and then when you finish you mark it as "done" so if someone its working in that user, the user is still available for others, so maybe you need a "working" boolean field so you can lock it when someone is working in it..

Comment: I think this is the best strategy for my situation. This is really creative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize mutexes to restrict access.

Without seeing the code base, I am not exactly sure where to place it.  You can use this to lock access so that only one user can query at a time.  Then release the mutex after one person has queried so that the next user can now access the DB.